# Backbone Layout Manager - Render not called

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-layout-manager

Here is an example code from the github of backbone layout manager.
The custom render for the view is not getting called/it doesn't stop on the break point.what is happening.

```
   // Create a Content view to be used with the Layout below.
    var ContentView = Backbone.Layout.extend({
      template: "#content"
    });

    // Create a new Layout with a sub view for content.
    var layout = new Backbone.Layout({
      template: "#layout",

      // This will place the contents of the Content View into the main
      // Layout's <p></p>.
      views: {
        // Appending a new content view using the array syntax
        p: new ContentView({
          // Custom render function that reverses everything.
          render: function(template, context) {
            return template(context).split("").reverse().join("");
          }
        })
      }
    });

    // Attach the Layout to the main container.
    layout.$el.appendTo(".main");

    // Render the Layout.
    layout.render();
```

Comment: Can you stick a demo together @ http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered by the Github when I posted the issue. it should be layout.renderTemplate()